# Any DTC Registered Brokers for Indian trying to exchange restricted units to ordinary shares?

Tags: non-resident, shares, broker

I am an ex-Broadcom (BRCM) employee laid off during 2014 Aug before it is sold to another company Avago. During my tenure at that company I received some RSU s which were converted to restricted units as Broadcom Cayman LP with two year lock in period. Now in 2017, I received a letter from ComputerShare (which were holding restricted units ) asking me to submit  an exchange request through a DTC registered broker. Now I read that only US citizens can get DTC brokers to pull shares for them . But what are the alternatives for Indians? What happens if I cannot do the exchange?